# view pager background image is not moving when scroll

Tags: android, android-fragments, scroll, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with 6 fragment.when i make android:hardwareAccelerated="true" the ViewPager background is moving fine.

when i open a activity from first fragment and come back to view pager activity the ViewPager background is moving fine.

but when i open activity from other fragments and comeback,the ViewPager background is not moving when scroll.
hope u understand my problem

I tried to do this...but still background image is not moving when scroll.

ViewPagerMainActivity

```
 try{
     if(getIntent().getStringExtra("about").equals("aboutus"))
       {
       myViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
       }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
  }


@Override
public void onResume() {  // After a pause OR at startup
    super.onResume();
    vpa.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Opened 2nd,3rd,.. Activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewPagerMainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("about","aboutus");
    startActivity(i);
}
```

I had notifyDataSetChanged() in onResume().when adapter is updated that background image is not moving when scroll.
how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the background is different for 6 different fragments, set background to individual fragment layout instead of Viewpager. Because of Viewpager is completely filled with fragment content.

Comment: I am using one image to all viewpages.
myViewPager.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgImg);

Comment: Set background to viewpager's parent layout instead of viewpager.

Comment: I already set same background image to parent layout .but the animation and background image move when scroll is not working

Comment: That problem was caused by the vpa.notifyDataSetChanged(); method.but i need to update the adapter.